# Partial Sorting/Re-ordering with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Firstly, my disclaimer is that I unfortunately have no code to provide with which I need assistance, as I have absolutely no idea how to approach this... :(

Basically - I have a Worksheet which has a number of rows of data, currently displayed in a very specific order. In column "C" of this Worksheet, the data is sorted by date order from earliest to latest. Then, in column "H" of this Worksheet there are unique numbers which identify each row. In a separate Worksheet, I have a list of these same numbers which might not necessarily be in the same order as those on the first Worksheet, and also does not include ALL of these unique numbers.

What I am looking for is some VBA code I could run which would essentially compare the rows on the first sheet to the numbers on the other sheet, and re-order the lines on the first sheet if necessary to match the order on the second sheet (without changed the date order). If the numbers don't appear on the second sheet, then the order should not be changed.

EG: Say I have the first sheet with columns "C" & "H" displaying as such:

```
    C          H
01/10/2016   **124**    
01/10/2016   **137**   
01/10/2016   **198**    
03/10/2016   **179**    
04/10/2016   **59**    
04/10/2016   **329**    
05/10/2016   **208**    
05/10/2016   **240**
```

Then the second sheet has only the following numbers on it, in this exact order:

```
C

**198**    
**137**    
**329**    
**59**
```

The code should then re-order/sort the initial data into the following exact order:

```
    C          H

01/10/2016   **124**    
01/10/2016   ***198***    
01/10/2016   ***137***    
03/10/2016   **179**    
04/10/2016   ***329***    
04/10/2016   ***59***    
05/10/2016   **208**    
05/10/2016   **240**
```

Is something like this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that column Z of sheet 1 is empty (you also can use another column as helper then simply:

```
=C1+(ROW()/10+IFERROR(MATCH(H1,Sheet2!C:C,0),0))/100000
```

And copy the formula down. Now sort for column Z. ;)